# how to put where clause variable in the 1st layer of select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting out of option in my query in putting select variable in the nearest query layer.

Getting this error `unknown column h.date` from this line `gb.startTime = h.date`

I know the cause, since I put the `h.date` inside the left join select. I think this is something wrong with the arrangement.

Does anyone have an idea?

this is my query:

```
set @maxBat = 10000;
set @minBat = 0;
select
    h.date,
    (select 
        count(*)
    from(
        select 
            distinct d.id, 
            d.reg,
            ifnull(bc.battleCount, 0) AS battles
        from (
            select 
                ds.id as id,
                ds.reg as reg
            ...
            ) as d
        left join
            (
            select 
                count(gb.id) as battleCount,
                gb.playerID
            from g_battles as gb
            where
                gb.startTime = h.date
            group by gb.playerID
            ) as bc on bc.playerID = d.id
        having battles between @minBat and @maxBat
        ) as e
            where e.reg = h.date
    ) as regbattle
from
    sessiontable as h
where
...
```

Comment: A subquery can only refer to tables in the immediately containing query, not multiple levels out.

Comment: So you can use `h.date` in the `regbattle` query, but not in `bc`.

Comment: You should try to convert this to joins instead of correlated subqueries.

Comment: The replacement for the correlated subquery is a query that uses `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use outside data query in just one level back subquery, not more, for example,

This is ok

```
select id,(select count(index_) 
from (select index_ from log_sops) as t where t.index_ = h.version) 
from data_sops as h where id = 4
```

But this is wrong

```
select id,(select count(index_) 
from (select index_ from log_sops where id = h.version) 
as t) 
from data_sops as h where id = 4
```